# Different optimization results for line-up competition algorithm of matlab and python

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, random

I tried to write the line-up competition algorithm on python and matlab, but the result of matlab is better than that of python every time, and the result of matlab is fixed value while the result of python is not fixed. I think it's a problem with random numbers or critical conditions, but after using the same random numbers and critical conditions later, the results in python are still not ideal.

This is my python code:

```
from function_ca import function_ca
import numpy as np
upper_bound = np.array([6, 6])
lower_bound = np.array([0, 0])
r = 0.999       
population = 10 
npoint = 5      
ul_bound = upper_bound - lower_bound
x = np.zeros((npoint, 2))
ll = np.array([0, 0])
bb = np.array([0, 0])
xx = np.zeros((population, 2))
for i in range(2):
    cacu_1 = lower_bound[i] + ul_bound[i]*np.random.rand(npoint, 1)
    x[:, i] = cacu_1.reshape((npoint, ))
y = function_ca(x)
m = 1

while max(ul_bound) >= 0.0000001:
    y1 = np.sort(y)
    k = np.argsort(y)
    x_t = x.repeat(repeats=1, axis=1)
    for i in range(len(k)):
        x[i, :] = x_t[k[i], :]
    for i in range(npoint):
        for j in range(2):
            ll[j] = max(x[i, j] - ul_bound[j] * i / (2 * npoint), lower_bound[j])
            bb[j] = min(x[i, j] + ul_bound[j] * i / (2 * npoint), upper_bound[j])
        for ii in range(2):
            caculate_2 = ll[ii] + (bb[ii] - ll[ii]) * np.random.rand(population, 1)
            xx[:, ii] = caculate_2.reshape((population,))

        yy = function_ca(xx)
        yy1 = np.sort(yy)
        kk = np.argsort(yy)
        if yy1[0] < y1[i]:
            x[i, :] = xx[kk[0], :]
            y1[i] = yy1[0]
    y = y1
    m += 1
    ul_bound = ul_bound * 0.99

print(m)
print(x)
print(y)
```

and this is my matlab code :

```
clear
close
%bounds of varibles 
l=[0 0];
b=[6 6];
% l=[100 1000 1000 10 10 10 10 10];
% b=[10000 10000 10000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000];
variable=size(l,2);
%r=input('contraction factor 0.1-0.99:');
%npoint=input('population number:');
%reprod=input('production number:');
r=0.999;
npoint=20;
reprod=10;
tim0=clock;
dbl=b-l;
for i=1:variable
   x(:,i)=l(i)+dbl(i)*rand(npoint,1);
end

y=funLCA(x);
m=1;
while max(dbl)>=0.000001%m<100%

    [y1,k]=sort(y);
    x=x(k,:);
  for i=1:npoint
    for j=1:variable
      ll(j)=max(x(i,j)-dbl(j)*i/(2*npoint),l(j));
      bb(j)=min(x(i,j)+dbl(j)*i/(2*npoint),b(j));
        end
    for ii=1:variable  
        xx(:,ii)=ll(ii)+(bb(ii)-ll(ii))*rand(reprod,1);
    end
    yy=funLCA(xx);
    
    [yy1,kk]=sort(yy);
    if yy1(1)<y1(i)
      x(i,:)=xx(kk(1),:);
      y1(i)=yy1(1);
    end
  end
y=y1;
m=m+1;
dbl=r*dbl;
end
time=etime(clock,tim0)
m
y=funLCA(x)
x
```

I think language will only affect the efficiency, but it will never affect the results.
I hope that experts can help me and tell me why this is happening.

Comment: Of course the language will effect the results, if only because the underlying algorithms have been coded differently, random numbers can be slightly different etc.

Comment: Also precision of float numbers may be different. ..

Comment: You could start debugging to find out where numbers start to be different in your two implementations.